# IOS, how to get device orientation at launch or viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, screen-orientation

I have an app that depending on the orientation shows different images... I have been using:

```
UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]);
```

To see if it is landsCape or not... but if I call this in my rootViewController: `viewDidLoad`,`viewWillAppear`, or`viewDidAppear` its always false.... then i was trying figure if its landsCape or no by comparing the width and height of a frame that has autosizeMask so it always is full screen... its a scroll view and I do the following:

```
BOOL landscape = self.frame.size.width>self.frame.size.height;
```

But that doesn't work either (always false) because the view still has the frame for the portrait view at that moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using device orientation, check for interface orientation. These macros will help you.

```
#define IS_PORTRAIT     UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])
#define IS_LANDSCAPE    UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])
```

Comment: These won't work correctly right at launch. This is because there is a slight delay before the statusBarOrientation is set correctly. I assume this is a safety mechanism to "force" us to create the views in portrait or use a work around like I have used in my apps before.

Comment: thanks... I totally forgot about statusBarOrientation

Answer (score 3):

You should do your layout in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.  At that point your view controller's view's `frame` will be set properly.

Using the `orientation` property is wrong.  From the docs:

> The value of the property is a constant that indicates the current orientation of the device. This value represents the physical orientation of the device and may be different from the current orientation of your application’s user interface.

Instead, you may want to use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`, which will match your UI's orientation in most cases.

Comment: Yes to using `viewWill LayoutSubviews`. Using `orientation` works fine for me, I think it may not be "wrong" if the device supports all orientations unless the admonition refers to cases where you are launching while rotating the device.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create a notification and then do your job accordingly!

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

try using this aswell

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation
```

returns portrait when it's landscape, and landscape when it's portrait at launch, in iPad

Comment: [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation won't return the correct value when app very first launches. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had an app that the launch orientation was critical for me to know. I was frustrated to learn that Apple's official position was that you should create your view in portrait. From the docs for `UIViewController`:

> At launch time, apps should always set up their interface in a
>   portrait orientation. After the
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method returns, the app
>   uses the view controller rotation mechanism described above to rotate
>   the views to the appropriate orientation prior to showing the window.

You can follow *Harsh*'s suggestion but it won't work…not quite how you need it to anyway. The reason why is that the correct orientation notification isn't generated for a second or so after the app has launched. I think *Aaron*'s suggestion of using `viewWillLayoutSubviews` might be worth looking into.

On my app I referred to above, I didn't load the view until I got the first legitimate notification of what orientation the device was in. Instead I just showed the launch image for a split second longer until I knew which orientation to set the view up with.